# Get parent `io` from `socket`

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

In Socket.IO you can send a message to **everyone** with the following:

```
const io = require("socket.io");
io.broadcast.emit("message", data);
```

You can also send a message to **everyone but one person** using a pattern like so:

```
const io = require("socket.io");
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.on("message", function(msg) {
        socket.broadcast.emit("message", msg);
    });
});
```

This allows for the creation of simple chat apps and the like

Now suppose I have the socket handler defined in another file:

```
// index.js
const io = require("socket.io");
const handler = require("./handler.js");
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.on("message", handler);
});

// handler.js
module.exports = function(socket) {
    socket.broadcast.emit("message", msg);
}
```

In this situation, I want to send a message to *everyone* - including the socket that initiated the message. So given the `socket`, how do I get access to its parent `io` object?

I've tried some things like:

```
socket.io.broadcast
socket.server.broadcast
socket.server.eio.broadcast
etc
```

But none of these seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about passing in the `io` to the handler? Originally the handler function would accept a payload (`msg` in your handler) not a socket?

```
// index.js
const io = require("socket.io");
const handler = require("./handler.js");
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.on("message", data => handler(io, data) );
});

// handler.js
module.exports = function(socket, msg) { 
    socket.broadcast.emit("message", msg);
}
```

Comment: You mean: `data => handler(socket, data)`

Comment: @RaphaMex normally yes, but he wanted the parent (io) to blanket broadcast.